# Translating MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

So I have this query in MySQL:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table majorequipment
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `majorequipment` (
    `MEId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `PACId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EquipmentNumber` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Comments` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ETId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Status` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Description` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Removed` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Active` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`MEId`),
    INDEX `PACId` (`PACId` ASC),
    INDEX `ETId` (`ETId` ASC),
    INDEX `fk_majorequipment_status_idx` (`Status` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_majorequipment_userdefinedcode_PACId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PACId`)
    REFERENCES `userdefinedcode` (`UDCId`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_majorequipment_userdefinedcode_ETId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ETId`)
    REFERENCES `userdefinedcode` (`UDCId`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_majorequipment_status`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Status`)
    REFERENCES `componentstatus` (`StatusName`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

And I am trying to convert it to SQL Server, though I am having some issues.

- `ON DELETE RESTRICT`: I am uncertain of the SQL equivalent of this. From what  I can tell it could be `NO ACTION`, but I am not sure.
- I am using SQL Fiddle (MS SQL 2014) and after replacing all the `ON DELETE RESTRICT` with `ON DELETE NO ACTION` it shows this error:

  > Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_majorequipment_userdefinedcode_ETId' on table 'majorequipment' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

---

Post-Note: I have already removed the '`' characters and the last two lines (`ENGINE` and `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET`)

Comment: By SQL do you mean the dialect supported by SQL Server?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah. We have all these functions used in MySQL, and we're translating them to be used in SQL Server as well

Answer (score 0):

In your table definition two foreign keys `PACId` and `ETId` point to the same master field in another table `UDCId`.

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_majorequipment_userdefinedcode_PACId`
FOREIGN KEY (`PACId`)
REFERENCES `userdefinedcode` (`UDCId`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE CASCADE,


CONSTRAINT `fk_majorequipment_userdefinedcode_ETId`
FOREIGN KEY (`ETId`)
REFERENCES `userdefinedcode` (`UDCId`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Apparently, SQL Server doesn't support this configuration with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

[Error message 1785 occurs when you create a FOREIGN KEY constraint that may cause multiple cascade paths](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321843)

**CAUSE**

> You receive this error message because in SQL Server, a table cannot
>   appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential
>   actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement.
>   For example, the tree of cascading referential actions must only have
>   one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions
>   tree.

**WORKAROUND**

> To work around this problem, do not create a foreign key that will
>   create more than one path to a table in a list of cascading
>   referential actions.
>
> You can enforce referential integrity in several ways. Declarative
>   Referential Integrity (DRI) is the most basic way, but it is also the
>   least flexible way. If you need more flexibility, but you still want a
>   high degree of integrity, you can use triggers instead.

Your table `majorequipment` appears in two foreign keys and SQL Server is too strict in this case.

So, you can change the constraints to `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` (it would be enough to change only one of the two), but you'll have to implement cascading updates yourself in your code or triggers. If you really need cascading updates.

Note, that you still can and should define both foreign keys. Only cascading actions should be implemented manually, for example, via triggers, if they are really needed.

Comment: Somehow MySQL doesn't have an issue with this. As for SQL however, I can't think of a way around this. These fields can be dealt with individually, so one *or* the other *or* both can be updated. How can we define this?

Comment: @Ben, It appears that SQL Server is very strict when defining cascade actions in foreign keys, compared to MySQL. Is it really a common use case for your system when a key  `userdefinedcode.UDCId` changes and these changes have to propagate to the linked table(s)? Usually primary key never changes...

Comment: Yes, it would be highly unlikely for this to occur, it's more of a safeguard in the off-chance that it does happen.

Comment: @Ben, if normally the value of primary key should not change, then the most appropriate setting for foreign key is `NO ACTION`, rather than `CASCADE`, in my opinion. I prefer an `UPDATE` query (which by mistake tries to change some value that it should not be changing) to fail, and you can detect and fix the bug in the code, rather than silently and unexpectedly updating many values in linked tables.